# Effect on water pressure of reducing pipe size

Tags: water, pipe, pressure

I have a lake pump that uses 1.5 inch pvc to deliver water 100 ft then the last two feet it reduces to a 3/4 pipe with a bib faucet. Am I losing water pressure, gaining or no difference with the reduction in pipe size?  Thank you

Comment: losing flow rate ... pressure drops more when a tap is opened

Comment: If your fawcet has a 3/4 inch inlet, then it doesnt matter.

Answer (score 3):

The actual size of the valve opening in the faucet is the major flow restriction here.

The pressure at any faucet is zero, if the faucet is open to atmosphere (not connected to a pipe or hose going onwards.) What actually changes is the flow rate from the faucet, and the head (pressure) loss in the pipes and valves leading to that point, which impact the flow rate.

If you block the faucet flow by attaching a pressure gauge (so no water is moving through the pipe) all pipe sizes don't matter and don't change the pressure.

Change to no 3/4" pipe & a 1-1/2" ball valve, you'll  see a difference in flow rate. *Depending on your pump, this may be more flow than it can sustain without damage, though.*

Remove the two feet of 3/4" pipe without changing the valve - you'll not be able to measure the difference, because the two feet of 3/4" is barely noticeable *.vs.* the inside of the faucet (not described as a ball valve.)

Change to a 3/4" ball valve, you'll see an improvement, but not as much as a larger ball valve on larger pipe.

Attach 100 feet of 5/8" garden hose to the bib and you're back to the 2 feet of 3/4" pipe making no perceptible difference at the end of the hose, and probably a ball valve would also make little difference, because the 100 feet of 5/8" would be the major restriction.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want to know is would the maximum flow rate increase (volume/time, with the valve wide open), if you would remove the short length of 3/4" tubing and maybe also change to a 1.5" valve. In the USA flow rate would be in units of gal/min and in metric litres/min or litres/second (L/min or L/s).

If you want to know if the flow rate available would be higher if you had 1.5 inch pipe all the way to a 1.5 inch valve, then the answer would be different depending on some factors:

(1) Unrestricted flow. If the valve would have nothing connected to it (e.g., the flow out of the valve would go through into an irrigation ditch or a watering trough), then the flow rate would be higher without the 3/4" pipe and valve IF the pump could pump more volume/time with less back pressure.

The 3/4" tubing and valve will act as a flow restrictor and increase the "back pressure" at the output side of the pump. With reduced backpressure the pump might pump at a higher flow rate or it might pump at the same flow rate but use less electric power depending on the characteristics of the pump.

(2) Restricted flow. If you have connected a long 3/4" or smaller hose on the valve (e.g., it is connected to the supply piping of a house or is connected to a long line to somewhere or to a long soaker hose), then there would be no benefit to removing the short length of 3/4" hose and the 3/4" valve because the restriction removed would be inconsequential. All the tubing following has much more resistance to flow than the 3/4" valve.

What, if anything, is connected to the valve? What is the power of the pump or its characteristics?

EDIT

Am I correct that it is the flow rate out of the valve that you are wondering about or is it really the pressure under maximum flow just before the valve you are concerned about? Do you have a pressure gauge or gauges connected to allow reading the pressure under flow conditions in the 1.5" tubing and in the 3/4" tubing and are youtrying to understand the reason these are different under flow?

My rudimentary knowledge of fluid dynamics tells me that in the current set-up in the short length of 3/4" tubing the "linear velocity" of the water under flow will be 4 times higher than the linear velocity of the water in the 1.5" tubing. This would lower the pressure measured in the 3/4" section compared to the 1.5" tubing. (The "volume flow rate" in the 3/4" section and the 1.5" section would be the same because they are in series and water is incompressible.)

But AFIK this is not really of interest to the user unless there would be a side T before the valve dividing the flow which you have not mentioned. A side T in the 1.5" line would have much more pressure under high flow than a side T in the 3/4" line.

Answer (score -1):

A pipe's capacity grows at the square of its radius or diameters growth.  So a 1 1/2 in pipe carries 4x the amount of water as a 3/4 in pipe.  Assuming the same total amount of water is coming out of the pipe, you have 4x the water pressure after reducing.  This assumes the pump is capable and there is no pressure regulating valves.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying the pressure is 4 times higher in the 3/4 inch section than in the 1 1/2 inch section, which isn't right.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: That is what I said.  X gpm in a 1.5 in pipe has y psi pressure.  The same gpm in a 0.75 in pipe has 4y psi.  Real world there would be some loss for inefficiency and pump style but not catastrophic.

Comment: I don't know where you found that relation, but it's not correct.  It has 4 times the velocity, but not 4 times the pressure.  If the pressure suddenly increased by a factor of 4, the flow would reverse.